# Integrating chatbot on shopify

Tags: shopify, chatbot, liquid, rasa

I have built an e-commerce website on shopify using Liquid template language. Now, I want to integrate a chatbot to it that I have built using Rasa framework. Is it possible? If yes, please share how I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your question requires a (very) long answer, quite unsuited to coding questions.
You are likely to find tutorials from either the Rasa Community sites or the Shopify sites.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Log in to your Shopify account. Click on Online Store.

[image: Shopify online store theme]

Open Shopify console

Step 2: Edit code
Navigate to the Themes section. Click on the Actions button and then click the Edit Code option.
[image: Shopify Edit Code]

Step 3: Add chatbot widget code. Rasa or any other bot provider will be providing the javascript snippet
In the Edit Code section, go to the left side Edit Code for Debut panel and click on Sections.

Open the footer -> liquid section and paste the copied chatbot javascript plugin script just below  tag. Click on Save. Preview & Publish
Above screenshot is taken from [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/shopify-chatbot/) but process is same for others.

[image: Section footer.liquid]